# Android: NoSuchFieldError referring to appcompat_v7 missing R$styleable.Theme_windowActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, runtime-error, android-appcompat

I am kind of new to Android development and I'm trying to work with the general structure of my app.
For now I have to show a **Splash Activity** for 3 secs and then pass to my **Main Activity**.

Since in my **S.A.** I don't need any ActionBar I thought that it was right not to make my class extend ActionBarActivity, but only Activity. Then I created an *Intent* starting my **M.A.**

These activities still don't have any real function.

Here my Splash Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent changeActivity = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(changeActivity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

And here my Main Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine to me **but** every time I try to run the app on my real device this is what I get:

> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Theme_windowActionBar
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:145)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:139)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at com.android.adiuvapp_verbalatina.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>
> 11-03 17:46:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(30179):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I've been searching the web for hours but there is no good answer to my question: *how can I solve this issue*?

Comment: It would be great if you post the code in your manifest and custom theme you are using(if any).

Comment: try adding your v7 appcompat library again

Answer (score 0):

use `extends Activity` instead of `extends ActionBarActivity` and the bug will be fixed.

Comment: You probably couldn't post an answer because it was too short. Using **boldface** probably wasn't helping either.

Comment: use walking instead of driving a car and you'll reach everywhere. really?

Comment: you can you up ,no can no bb